# spring security for REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I don't know whether it is already under development or not as spring project, but i strongly that there should be separate spring security for REST API. Right now we use and customize spring security to address REST API requirement but basically it is addressed to web mvc. Personally i face lots of challenge to handle REST API security requirement and i believe other developers also. If spring can provide such standard security framework for REST API, will be great. Comments please!!!

Comment: What challanges are you facing? Spring SEC is great for securing REST API-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can involve to look deeply inside the spring security docs and inside the blog (and certainly the book too) of Eugen Parashiv you will find in http://www.baeldung.com

[Search on Baeldung website for Spring Security, REST API](https://www.baeldung.com/?s=Spring+Security%2C+REST+API)

I can tell Spring Security is a great tool to secure many applications, and not only web ones! SWT or SWING ones too, because of endpoints secured techniques :)

Comment: Thanks ThierryB, i will read this and may be come up with more fine suggestions.

Comment: your link is dead it is possible to update it ?

Comment: @MrSolarius : update done, to relative contents and not a fixed blog article on his website, so you'll get more significant results for your working context.

Comment: And the previous one link I have provided is somewhere here : https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring

Answer (score 0):

How about using the built-in *remember-me* feature? Just mimicking the browsers, first time when a user signs in, have the remember-me flag set and preserve the returned remember-me cookie. Next time onward, send the cookie along with the requests.